# Setting up pymysql to work with django, pytest and pytest-django

Tags: python, django, pytest, pymysql, pytest-django

I have a Django website set up along with tests based on the `pytest` and `pytest-django` packages. I wish to get the `PyMySQL` package to work with my setup for testing and production.

I understand that in order to get PyMySQL to expose itself as a `mysqldb`
module so django (and other modules) can work with it I should place the following snippet at the beginning of my code.

```
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

I made several attempts to call above function at different locations throughout my code but none seem to be detected by pytest early enough.

This includes placing the snippet inside `conftest.py:pytest_configure`, in my django project's `manage.py` file, etc. Neither worked.

The reason I'm switching from `mysqlclient` to `PyMySQL` is that `mysqlclient` doesn't seem to be functioning with travis.org once I include the following in `.travis.yml`:

```
addons:
  mariadb: '10.0'
```

In order to use MariaDB instead of vanilla MySQL.

Getting travis to work with the python `mysqlclient` package will also solve my problem, however I could not get that done either.

For reference, [this](https://travis-ci.org/nirizr/rematch/jobs/404169175) is a travis job for the PR, in case I missed something important out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, at first I thought that's impossible to do because `pytest-django` imports a lot of `django` stuff on module level already, and you can't beat that by plugging yourself via hooks - they are all executed after the plugins are loaded via entry points, so `django` will be already imported by then.

However, looking at `pytest --help`, notice a rarely used option that turns out to be helpful in this case:

```
$ pytest --help
...
test session debugging and configuration:
  -p name               early-load given plugin (multi-allowed). To avoid
                        loading of plugins, use the `no:` prefix, e.g.
                        `no:doctest`.
```

#### Run `pymysql` configuration via plugin early loading

So custom plugins passed via `-p` arg will be imported earlier than the ones loaded via entrypoints. The solution is now easy: write a small module that imports and configures `pymysql` and pass it via `-p` arg:

```
# rematch/pymysql_hack.py
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

Tests invocation:

```
$ PYTHONPATH=. pytest -p pymysql_hack -rapP server tests/server
```

I forked the `rematch` project to test this out, [the jobs are looking good](https://travis-ci.org/hoefling/rematch/builds/404201082) (the first job fails because I was too lazy to add `pymysql` in all the requirements files).

#### Give up `pytest`, use `manage.py test`

Alternatively (this was my first solution proposal), you can run tests via `manage.py`, so you could add the `pymysql` configuration lines on top of `manage.py`, implement a custom test runner as described in [`pytest-django`'s FAQ](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-can-i-use-manage-py-test-with-pytest-django):

> pytest-django is designed to work with the `pytest` command, but if you really need integration with `manage.py test`, you can create a simple test runner like this:
>
> ```
> class PytestTestRunner(object):
>     """Runs pytest to discover and run tests."""
>
>     def __init__(self, verbosity=1, failfast=False, keepdb=False, **kwargs):
>         self.verbosity = verbosity
>         self.failfast = failfast
>         self.keepdb = keepdb
>
>     def run_tests(self, test_labels):
>         """Run pytest and return the exitcode.
>
>         It translates some of Django's test command option to pytest's.
>         """
>         import pytest
>
>         argv = []
>         if self.verbosity == 0:
>             argv.append('--quiet')
>         if self.verbosity == 2:
>             argv.append('--verbose')
>         if self.verbosity == 3:
>             argv.append('-vv')
>         if self.failfast:
>             argv.append('--exitfirst')
>         if self.keepdb:
>             argv.append('--reuse-db')
>
>         argv.extend(test_labels)
>         return pytest.main(argv)
> ```
>
> Add the path to this class in your Django settings:
>
> ```
> TEST_RUNNER = 'my_project.runner.PytestTestRunner'
> ```

and invoke the tests via

```
$ python manage.py test <django args> -- <pytest args>
```

However, you won't be able to run the tests via direct invocation of `pytest` with this solution.

Comment: Wow! This looks great! Thanks a lot for the detailed solution and going through all the trouble of testing this

Comment: Glad I could help! Great question btw.

Comment: Thanks. I often feel most of my questions are without answer. I can't seem to force the `pymysql_hack` file to reside inside the tests directory, though. Any quick pointers?

Comment: For Python 3, this should work out of the box with passing `-p tests.pymysql_hack`, Python 3 will simply treat `tests` as an implicit namespace package. However, implicit namespace packages are not defined in Python 2. I guess the appropriate path adjusting, something like `PYTHONPATH=".:tests" pytest -p pymysql_hack ...`, should work with Python 2; if not, you'll probably need to turn `tests` into a package for a cross-python solution.

Comment: Cool. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve the same issue by adding

```
import pymysql

pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

to my python3.6/site-packages/pytest_django/**init**.py file